# Wrap jquery event handler around hardcoded handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have several forms which look like this:

```
<form id=myForm onsubmit="saveFormData(this);return false">
....
</form>
```

Upon submission, a custom function is executed and the default action (sending the data through http) is canceled.

But now I need to validate the form and if it validates ok, then trigger the custom function (`saveFormData` in this case, but it may be different for other forms), otherwise do nothing.

So the final event handler should work like this:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(){
    if(formValidatesOk(this))
        saveFormData() ;
    return false ;
}
```

However, I cant make changes to the HTML code, so I need a general way of redefining the onsubmit event by wrapping the hardcoded handler with a jquery event handler.

The first thing that comes to my mind is something like (untested):

```
var hardcodedHandler = $('#myForm').prop('onsubmit') ; // save the current handler
$('#myForm').prop('onsubmit',null) ; // remove the current handler
$('#myForm').submit(function(){
    if(formValidatesOk(this)) // if the form is valid then...
        Function(hardcodedHandler).call(this) ; // trigger the original handler
    return false ;
}) ;
```

But that's not very elegant (to say the least).

Do you know of a better way of doing it?

Comment: Is anything in `formValidatesOk` asynchronous? If not, why don't you **only** `return false;` when the result of `formValidatesOk` is `false`? So the logic would be "If formValidatesOk returns true, also execute the original `onsubmit`...else, stop default behavior (return false)". Which would be `if (!formValidatesOk(this)) return false;` and that's it. Or are you saying you don't want the default behavior to ever happen?

Comment: I dont want the form to be submitted via http. But I do want the hardcoded handler (`saveFormData` in the example) to be triggered if the form validates ok.

Comment: @Ian, how can I be sure that the jquery handler will be triggered BEFORE the hardcoded handler?

Comment: Ahh I see, I hadn't thought of that. That's why I wanted to talk it out :) I would look at Bergi's answer...hadn't thought `prop` would be different than `attr` and get what you actually want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just take the old function from the `onsubmit` property of the element, you don't need to `eval` it:

```
var form = $('#myForm');
var oldHandler = form.prop("onsubmit");
form.removeProp("onsubmit").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(formValidatesOk(this))
        oldHandler.call(this, e);
});
```

[Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/xW4vj/)

Answer (score 0):

Events are unpredictable (in the way they get fired). I think that handers, bounded to them, must not rely on order either. So binding a handler to a event which changes the previous added handler is certainly a (very) bad practice. And indeed, as you suggested, you can never be sure which handler will be triggered first. After all, events should have no notice of each other. One should use events and handlers to avoid high coupling of the code.

The best way to approach this issue (taking your constraints into account) is to decorate your 'old' handler with the new behaviour. Bergi posted a nice example of this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure events are always executed in the order they were bound. Of course, the OP is a different situation because some are bound with jQuery, some inline. But in that case, the inline ones should execute first because they were bound first (as soon as the element was parsed/rendered)

Comment: Ian, thanks for your comment! It should be handlers in stead of events, I will update my answer. Events are unpredicted occurrences, handlers are functions registered to them. Nevertheless, I don't think one should rely on the order of both of them, events and handlers in the way they are added. Also, handlers should have no notice of each other. If so, wrap them inside one handler to ensure proper order and proper execution (check if the depended function executed properly). Of course, the jQuery implementation will execute them in the order they are added but this is 'just' implementation.